# how to reduce the distance between the picture caption and the picture?

Tags: spacing, captions

I found that the distance between the picture caption and the picture is a little large, as we can see in the picture[image]

I use the code as follows, thus, how to reduce the distance between the caption and the picture?

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.pathmorphing}
 \begin{figure}[ht!]
{\centering
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=1.0cm, sibling distance=0.5cm}}
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,  edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=2mm}}]
    {\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(\{a{\mapsto}1\},A{<}a{=}1{>}B,t_{i_1}{\geq}0,0)$}
         child{edge from parent node{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_{n-1}{:}(...,stop_{good},t_{i_3}{\geq}3,0)$}
    };
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{LTS of A Pick Activity}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the `skip` key of the `caption` package; I used a value of `2pt`, but you can choose the length that best suits your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.pathmorphing}
 \begin{figure}[ht!]
{\centering
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=1.0cm, sibling distance=0.5cm}}
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,  edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=2mm}}]
    {\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(\{a{\mapsto}1\},A{<}a{=}1{>}B,t_{i_1}{\geq}0,0)$}
         child{edge from parent node{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_{n-1}{:}(...,stop_{good},t_{i_3}{\geq}3,0)$}
    };
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{LTS of A Pick Activity}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The spaces before and after a caption are controlled by `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`. Thus you can change the distance before the caption with

```
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0cm}
```

Change the value as appropriate.