# Cutting the size between caption and image

Tags: formatting

Basically is the title of the question possible if i am using a standard figure is it possible to cut the size between the figure and its caption?

Comment: @Papiro: Good find; yes...

Comment: You could try using the `caption` package

Comment: As suggested in the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67152/5764) to [how to reduce the distance between the picture caption and the picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67143/5764), the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) can help with this (and is preferred). Give some feedback as to whether this solves your problem. Then we might close this question as a duplicate (for housekeeping purposes).